# Hi, Is there any way to know how many objects are referencing other object?

Tags: rigging, objects, constraints, drivers

Example- I have a object named Master. Master object is used as a reference in many drivers and constraints(like master object rotation is used in some driver and it is also referenced in constraints like Limit distance constraint). So, is there any way to list all those references where Master object or its properties are used.
In my case I am using someone else rig and it has many bones,constraints,drivers etc and I can't able to understand the connections between them so I thought it would be cool If i could check which thing is used for what?